# Lipschitz Continuous in ever bounded set and not Lipschitz Continuous in every non-bounded set!

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Prove that the function $f(x) = x^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>2$:
a. is Lipschitz continuous in every bounded interval.
b. is not Lipschitz continuous in every non-bounded interval.

**My attempt:** I've tried to prove it's Lipschitz and I ended up finding that $C=|x_1^{n-1} - x_2^{n-1}| >0$. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: This is clearly homework. What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I thought to try to prove that |f(x1)-f(x2)| <= C|x1-x2|. In that way we will firstly prove it's Lipschitz... Then I don't know... :p

Comment: Once you've got to the stage of $C\cdot|x_1-x_2|$ you need to look at the type of interval you've got.  If you have a bounded interval, what can you say about $C$?  Is there something you can say about $\sup_{x,y\in[a,b]}C$ for example?

Comment: Prove something more general instead:  If $f:[a,b]\to R$ has a continuous derivative (or even just a bounded derivative) then $f$ is Lipschitz on $[a,b]$.  This is easier than messing with derivative computations [not that $x^n$ is hard to differentiate].  The (b) is specific to the example and has to be checked.